# Disable drop in childs of div (Html5 drag and drop )

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

HTML

```
    <div id="participants" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width:400px; min-height:300px; display:inline; float:left; border: 1px solid black;">
        <h3 style="margin:10px;">Participants</h3>
    </div>



    <div id="users" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width:400px; min-height:300px; float:right; border: 1px solid black;" >

<p class="draggable" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="return false;" >draggable content</p>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
allowDrop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

drag = function(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

drop = function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    if (data) {
        var childElement = document.getElementById(data);
        if (childElement) {
            ev.target.appendChild(childElement);
        }
    }
}
```

The following code works fine, but I only want things to be moved from one div to another. Right now you can also drop a p inside another p (even though I tried to prevent this with ondrop="return false;").

How can I disable p tags to be dropped inside other p tags? 
Note: the draggable elements are inserted by jQuery.html method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My temp solution is to check the class before dropping (added class droppable to the 2 divs: users and participants)

```
drop = function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            if (data) {
                var childElement = document.getElementById(data);
                if (childElement) {
                    if($(ev.target).hasClass( "droppable" ))    {           //Only allow drop inside the 2 divs
                        ev.target.appendChild(childElement);
                    }
                    if($(ev.target).hasClass( "draggable" ))    {           //put in parent when dropped on draggable
                        console.log('$(ev.target).parent()', $(ev.target).parent());
                        $(ev.target).parent()[0].appendChild(childElement);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: $(ev.target).hasClass() method can be used to check the exact DIV element where the object should be dropped. This idea is working in my code. Thank  you.

Answer (score 1):

i encountered the same unwanted behavior. i worked around it in this way:

```
if (ev.target.nodeName == 'LI') {
  $(ev.target).after(draggedNode);
} else {
  $(ev.target.closest('li')).after(draggedNode);
}
```

this code assumes a DOM structure something like this, where desired drop target is the list item, and unwanted drop target is the span:

```
...
  <li>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span></span>
  </li>
...
```